# Checking if parenthesis are balanced or not using Stack?

Tags: java, stack, expression, parentheses

I have written a java code to test if an expression is balanced or not, that is, this program checks if the characters '(', '{' and '[' have a corresponding delimiter or not. However I am unable to get the required answer. There is something wrong and I am unable to figure it out and hence would need your help. Here is the code.

```
package z_Stack_InfixToPostfix;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Driver_InfixToPostfix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="(a+b)";
        System.out.println(checkBalance(s));
    }

    public static boolean checkBalance(String expression){
        boolean isBalanced=true;
        Stack<Character> myStack=new Stack<Character>();
        int length=expression.length();
        int i=0;
        while(isBalanced && i<length){
            switch(expression.charAt(i)){
            case '(': case '{': case '[' :
                myStack.push(expression.charAt(i));
                break;
            case ')': case '}': case ']':
                if(myStack.isEmpty()){
                    isBalanced=false;
                }
                else{
                    char opendelimiter=myStack.pop();
                    if(opendelimiter!=expression.charAt(i)){
                        isBalanced=false;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(!myStack.isEmpty()){
            isBalanced=false;
        }
        return isBalanced;
    }
}
```

Comment: `There is something wrong` - can you give an example input for which the output is not what you expect?

Comment: I gave an example input in my main method. It's (a+b). It should be balanced and my checkBalance method should return true, but I keep getting false.

Comment: What answer are you expecting for `([}]`?

Comment: @shmosel It would be false right? It would add '(' and '[' to the stack and when it encounters '}', it will go to second set of cases in my switch statement and there since '[' and '{' are not equal, isBalanced would be set to false and exit the loop right?

Comment: @rohitkrishna094, well not really. Your code is not differentiating between any class of delimiter. Though perhaps that was the intention of `if(opendelimiter!=expression.charAt(i))`, as some of the answers explain.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I just figured that out too. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char opendelimiter=myStack.pop();
if(opendelimiter!=expression.charAt(i)){
       isBalanced=false;
}
```

Here you should check

```
    if(openedDeimilter == '('){
        if(expression.charAt(i)!=')'){
            isBalanced=false;
            //break;
        }
    }else if(openedDeimilter == '['){
        if(expression.charAt(i)!=']'){
           isBalanced=false;
           //break;
        }
    }else {
         if(expression.charAt(i)!='}'){
            isBalanced=false;
            //break;
        }
    }
```

Also once isBalanced is set to `false` you can skip iterating the remaining string, if it suits you.

Answer (score 1):

What about a different approach using only the length of your expression without each parentheses? This will let you not use the Stack class and should be more efficient for longer expression

```
public static boolean checkBalance(String expression) {
   String[] parentheses = new String[]{"\\(|\\)","\\[|\\]","\\{|\\}"};
   int length = expression.length();
   for(int i=0; i<parentheses.length; i++) {
       int newLength = expression.replaceAll(parentheses[i], "").length();
       int diff = length - newLength;
       if(diff % 2 != 0) {
          return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

The double backslash are used to escape each parentheses because they are special characters

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
if(opendelimiter!=expression.charAt(i)){
    isBalanced=false;
}
```

You check if two chars are equal, but the correct check should match the 2 corresponding chars: `[` - `]`, `(` - `)` and `{` - `}`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


char exp[1028];
char ext[1028];

int top = -1;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
push(char x){

    top++;
    ext[top]=x;
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void pop(){
    top--;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


main()
{
int ans;
char in='{';
char it='[';
char ie='(';

char an;'}';
char at=']';
char ae=')';
printf("\nenter your expression\n");
gets(exp);
int j=strlen(exp);
int i;
for(i=0;i<=j;i++){
    if(exp[i] == in || exp[i] == it || exp[i]==ie){
        push(exp[i]);
        }
    if(exp[i] == an ||exp[i]== at || exp[i]==ae){
        pop();
    }
}
if(top == -1){
    printf("\nexp is balanced\n");
    }
else{
    printf("\nexp is unbalanced");
}
}
```